# Realloc only works twice

Tags: c, realloc

For some reason, when I realloc an array to append an item to the array, it only works twice before segfaulting. The segfault occurs when I try to print the strings inside of the array. I currently have an array which is `NULL` terminated.

```
void apparr(char** arr, char* line) {
    int length = 0;
    // find the length of the array
    while(arr[length] != NULL) {
        length++;
    }
    // realloc with 2 extra spaces (1 for line, 1 for NULL)
    arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(char*) * (length+2));
    // set last element (which was NULL) to line
    arr[length] = line;
    // set the NULL terminator
    arr[length+1] = NULL;
}
```

I have no clue where I could be going wrong here, my only guess would be with how I am calling realloc. However, I would understand that not working for 1 resize, but I have no clue why this works for two resizes then segfaults when I am printing back the array.

How it could be used in main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
char** hist = malloc(sizeof(char**));
char* linep1;
char* linep2;
char* linep3;
char* linep4;
linep1 = (char*)malloc(strlen("test")*sizeof(char));
linep2 = (char*)malloc(strlen("test2")*sizeof(char));
linep3 = (char*)malloc(strlen("test3")*sizeof(char));
linep4 = (char*)malloc(strlen("test4")*sizeof(char));   
strcpy(linep1, "test");
strcpy(linep2, "test2");
strcpy(linep3, "test3");
strcpy(linep4, "test4");
apphist(hist, linep1);
apphist(hist, linep2);
//apphist(hist, linep3); //uncommenting this line causes nothing to be printed
//apphist(hist, linep4); //uncommenting this line causes only test4 to be printed
int x = 0;
while (hist[x] != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", hist[x]);
    x++;
}
}
```

Comment: I hope you are not passing an actual array, because realloc is not meant to be used on arrays. Its for dynamic memory allocation while trying to retain the same base address.

Comment: It’s a “malloc”ed array pointer @Mihir

Comment: Please create a [mcve] which reproduces the issue that you have.

Comment: You're making changes locally to `arr` which don't get reflected in the calling function.

Comment: @dbush I pass in a pointer to arr not an arr. Therefore the changes get reflected when I realloc the pointer.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje I figured you could use it in a main you made, but I provided one for you.

Comment: "*I have an array which is NULL terminated.*" initially you have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the main function you need to set the first element of `hist` as `NULL` as you are checking it in the function `apphist`

   ```
   char** hist = malloc(sizeof(char*));
   *hist = NULL;
   ```
2. The function `apphist` only changes the value of `arr` locally. To reflect the changes in the main function, you need to pass a pointer to a `arr` i.e. a 3D pointer `char ***arr`
3. You should always check the result of `realloc` and perform actions on failure.

Code for the function is below.

```
void apparr(char*** arr2, char* line) {
    int length = 0;
    char **arr = *arr2;
    while(arr[length] != NULL) {
        length++;
    }
    arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(char*) * (length+2));
    if (arr == NULL) {
        exit(1); // handle error 
    }        
    *arr2 = arr;   
    arr[length] = line;
    arr[length+1] = NULL;
}
```

4. Alternatively, you can return a pointer to a pointer to char and update the value in main.

```
char** apparr(char** arr, char* line) {
    int length = 0;
    char **temp;
    while(arr[length] != NULL) {
        length++;
    }
    temp = realloc(arr, sizeof(char*) * (length+2));
    if (temp == NULL) {
        exit(1); // handle error 
    }
    arr = temp;
    arr[length] = line;
    arr[length+1] = NULL;
    return (arr);
}    

//in main
hist = apphist(hist, linep1);
hist = apphist(hist, linep2);
```

Comment: This `char** hist = malloc(sizeof(char**));` has to be `char** hist = malloc(sizeof (char*));` or even nicer `char** hist = malloc(sizeof *hist);`.

Comment: Also those to assignments `arr[length] = line;
    arr[length+1] = NULL;` refer to invalid memory, as the relocation already happend.

Comment: “The function apphist only changes the value of arr locally.” This is proved wrong by the behavior of main.

Comment: @thebusybee `char ** arr` is a local variable in the function. Changing the value `arr` itself will not reflect in the main function

Comment: The code in 4 is still broken for the same reason as mention in my 2nd comment (where "*relocation* should read "reallocation").

Answer (score 0):

I think you should dereference the arr before you use in realloc. Another observation; the sizeof(char*) is usually 4 in 32 bit architecture and 8 in 64 bit instead of 1.

Comment: its an array of pointers... would it make sense for it to be 1? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For the general case I think you only need to  call realloc with length +1

```
arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(char*) * (length+1));
```

This is because you already had space for the NULL terminating pointer from the prior state. With the code you are proposing what's happening is something like this

// state prior to realloc

String String NULL

// apparr() call

String String NULL undefined undefined // realloc

String String String undefined undefined // arr[length] = line;

String String String NULL undefined // arr[length+1] = NULL;

The first time it will work (leaving a dangling allocated node at the end) but the second time it can crash in multiple ways due to the extra allocation.

Comment: The `strlen("string") + 1` part is correct.  I'm not sure I follow the rest, but the key point is that the `strcpy()` operations write outside the bounds of the allocated arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code:

1. **This is your main error.** You don't replace the value in the given pointer. It's correct to use a pointer to the pointer, but you need to dereference it. For this you need to pass the pointer to `hist` and dereference it at the re-allocation:

   ```
   *arr = realloc(*arr, sizeof(char*) * (length + 2));
   ```
2. The list of pointers is not initialized, after the first allocation you need to set the first pointer:

   ```
   hist[0] = NULL;
   ```
3. The allocations for your test strings are 1 off:

   ```
   linep1 = malloc((strlen("test") + 1) * sizeof(char));
   linep2 = malloc((strlen("test2") + 1) * sizeof(char));
   linep3 = malloc((strlen("test3") + 1) * sizeof(char));
   linep4 = malloc((strlen("test4") + 1) * sizeof(char));
   ```

Additional notes:

- The includes are missing for a complete [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
- The name `apparr()` is wrong, you call `apphist()` in `main()`.
- Check the return values of any allocation for NULL, meaning that the allocation failed.
- You don't use `argc` and `argv`, so write `int main(void)`
- The first allocation has the "wrong" type, but both are pointers, so it's the same size: `char** hist = malloc(sizeof(char*));`
- There is no need to cast pointers returned by `malloc()` as it returns a pointer to `void`. Pointers to `void` and other pointers can be assigned back and forth without casts.
- You can replace the `malloc()`/`strcpy()` pairs with `strdup()`.
- You can even call `apphist()` with the string as "immediate" value like this: `apphist(hist, "test");`
- `main()` should return an `int`, `EXIT_SUCCESS` is the right value.
- You can put some `const` at the parameters and declarations to make things safer. But think about *what* is constant.

Comment: This is taken from a larger peice of code. I added the mcve because people were upset and couldn’t think of how to use the original code themselves. I use argc and argv in that larger price of code. I cast for clarity. Just please think about how the program I am using this in could be larger than what is shown to you. What I show to you is for clarity not completeness.

Comment: Most sources shown here are just excerpts. No offend, but it's you who needs help, not us. ;-) So, please, take the time to prepare a clear example, instead of letting everyone have to find out what is missing and add that. It's much more efficient if the one expert on the code (that's you) invest a little time than multiple others each more time.

Comment: About the "cast for clarity": What is needed to be clarified? A variable of type `char *` receives a pointer to memory that is allocated as some number of `char`. No need for an extra cast.

Answer (score 0):

All errors and may pitfalls have been mentioned by others already.

Below find a more general implementation of the append-element-to-array function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h> /* for EINVAL */

int apparr(char *** parr, char * line) {
  size_t length = 0;

  if (NULL == *parr) {
    if (NULL != line) {
      errno = EINVAL;
      return -1;
    }
  } else {
    // find the length of the array
    while (NULL != (*parr)[length]) {
      ++length;
    }
  }

  {
    // realloc with 2 extra spaces (1 for line, 1 for NULL)
    void * pv = realloc(*parr, (length+1) * sizeof **parr);
    if (NULL == pv) {
      return -1; /* By convention -1 indicates failure. */
    }

    *parr = pv;
  }

  (*parr)[length] = line;
  if (0 < length) {
    (*parr)[length + 1] = NULL;
  }

  return 0; /* By convention 0 indicates success. */
}
```

And use it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int apparr(char *** parr, char * line) {

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char ** hist = NULL;
  char * linep1;
  char * linep2;
  char * linep3;
  char * linep4;

  if (-1 == apparr(&hist, NULL)) {
    perror("apphist() failed initially\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  linep1 = malloc(strlen("test") + 1);
  linep2 = malloc(strlen("test2") + 1); /* +1 for the c-string's 0-termination; sizeof (char) is 1 by definition */
  linep3 = malloc(strlen("test3") + 1);
  linep4 = malloc(strlen("test4") + 1);

  strcpy(linep1, "test");
  strcpy(linep2, "test2");
  strcpy(linep3, "test3");
  strcpy(linep4, "test4");

  if (-1 == apphist(&hist, linep1)) {
    perror("apphist() failed for line 1\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (-1 == apphist(&hist, linep2) {
    perror("apphist() failed for line 2\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (-1 == apphist(&hist, linep3) {
    perror("apphist() failed for line 3\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (-1 == apphist(&hist, linep4)  {
    perror("apphist() failed for line 4\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  {
    size_t x = 0;
    while (hist[x] != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", hist[x]);
      ++x;
    }
  }
}
```